# How to search and format a text range?

Tags: search, formatting, range

I want to format a block of text and I am using a range to select the leading comment of a function. It's all lines starting with `// ...`.

I'm using the range

```
:?^[^\/][^\/]?+1,/^[^\/][^\/]/-1
```

to select backwards up to the first line not starting with `//`, then plus one to get the the start of the comment, and similar thing for the forward search.

If I prefix this with a sed command like `s,^,#,` this works. But if I use `gq` or `gw` as command it fails telling me `Not an editor command: ...`

How can I apply the text format command to a range?

Comment: `gq` and `gw` are normal commands: you can't enter them in command mode like `:gq...` that's why you get `Not an editor command`. You can use `normal gq` to use them in a script.

Answer (score 2):

Per @statox comment...

Using normal commands applied to ranges is the same as when they are used in scripts, requiring the `normal` function to be called.

```
:?^[^\/][^\/]?+1,/^[^\/][^\/]/-1norm gq
```

A very common example of this is applying a macro to each line in a visually selected area. Lets say you want to uppercase the last word on each line:

```
qq$viwUq
```

If you visually select an area and enter command mode you can apply the macro using `normal`

```
:'<,'>normal @q
```